Plotting the count of several binary variables in R with ggplot
I have a dataset of a person-specific id variable and five binary variables, namely the results of tests on several sexually transmittable infections (STI). So every line is a person and every column is an STI that can be either 0 (negative) or 1 (positive).
 id             result_ct result_gn result_lues result_hiv_lab result_hiv_rapid
   <chr>              <dbl>     <dbl>       <dbl>          <dbl>            <dbl>
 1 xxxxxxxxxxxxx1         0         0           0              0                0
 2 xxxxxxxxxxxxx2         0         0           0              0                0
 3 xxxxxxxxxxxxx3         0         1           0              0                0
 4 xxxxxxxxxxxxx4         0         0           0              0                0

I'd like to have a plot with all 5 variables on the x axis and their total count plotted in bars. Basically, the plot should just add all "1"s of the variable "result_ct" of the whole dataset, say it adds up to 20, and display a bar accordingly, the same for the other four variables.
I guess that the dataset should be in long format for that, what I already accomplished (example below), but now I don't know what to do with it. Many thanks for your help!
                id         variable value
1   xxxxxxxxxxxxx1        result_ct     0
2   xxxxxxxxxxxxx2        result_ct     0
3   xxxxxxxxxxxxx3        result_ct     0
4   xxxxxxxxxxxxx1        result_gn     0
5   xxxxxxxxxxxxx2        result_gn     1
6   xxxxxxxxxxxxx2        result_gn     0

The best I could do until now was
ggplot(long, aes(value)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(fill=variable), position="dodge") 

What didn't help, because the STI variable shouldn't be the fill-variable but directly on the x axis.

It's easier to help you if share data in a reproducible format that we can copy/paste into R for testing. Make a simple example that avoids ... so the code will actually run.

You probably just want ggplot(long, aes(variable, value)) + geom_col()
